# Regular Expression for alpha/numeric characters, spaces and dashes

Tags: python, regex

I need some help writing a couple of complex regular expression that are way over my head.

The first Regex, I want to exclude everything **except**:

- The letters A to Z in both upper and lowercase
- Single spaces
- Single Dashes (-)

For the second, I want the same as above but also allow:

- The numbers 0 to 9
- Apostrophes (')
- Question Marks (?)
- Exclamation Marks (!)
- Colons & Semi-Colons (: & ;)
- Periods/Fullstops & commas (. & ,)

As a side note, are there any online generators that i can type a list of allowed characters into that will generate one for me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To satisfy the "single" requirement, you'll need a lookeahead, along the lines of:

```
r1 = r"""(?xi)
    ^
    (
        [a-z]+          
        |               
        \x20(?!\x20)    
        |               
        -(?!-)          
    )
    +
    $
"""
```

`\x20(?!\x20)` reads "a space, if not followed by another space".

For the second re, just add extra chars to the first group: `[a-z0-9&+ etc]`.